# Populate Column Default Value Inside Database Entity Framework Model First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-model-first

Is there any EF Model-First approach to populate LastModified column to `GetDate()` function in database.

Most of my [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/691035/1431250) took me to code-first alternatives. But could find Model-First approach. I see StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed in properties window.

Can you please tell me how to use this to populate date using `GetDate ()` function in database.

Comment: GETDATE() is a sql server function...EF is C#...are you trying to tell sql server to generate the date or is your application going to generate the date and then send it to sql server?

Comment: @BillRuhl, Telling SQL server to generate the date.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221137/datecreated-and-datemodified-in-asp-net-mvc-5/27221287#27221287), I believe you need to do same thing to Because eventually your date property needs to be set from the C# code, Or you can do it from the database level through triggers for example.